# Counting number of integers in text file (undeclared identifier using fin>>x)

Tags: c++, file, loops, fstream, undeclared-identifier

I have a text file with an unknown number of integers. I created a dynamic array without trouble, but the numbers have varied spacing and digits. I would normally go through each position to count the number of spaces used, subtracting space from it, but that won't work in this case.

I thought to use something like this: (which similar questions would suggest)

```
    do
    {

        if (!file.is_open())
        {
            file.open(donation);
        }

        fin >> temp;
        charCount++;
    } 
    while (file.peek() != EOF);

    cout << charCount;
```

Now, I have fstream included, and I am using namespace std, and I have no problem opening and reading the text file, but visual studio 2015 tells me:

Error   C2065   'fin': undeclared identifier

I don't understand what I am doing that is triggering that type of response from the IDE.

Comment: OK, could you guys STOP down voting this? I'd rather not get banned for life because you don't like the question. So I overlooked something. It's still a well written question that is simple and to the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file` is the name of your `ifstream`, right? If so, line

```
fin >> temp;
```

should be

```
file >> temp;
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I missed that!